# How do I edit file responses on Google Forms after submission

Tags: google-forms

On a Google form that allowed me to edit my responses after submission, there was a question that asked me to add a file. I did just that and turned it in. Now I want to replace that file. I can edit regular text-based responses but I can't replace or delete files. Is there any way to do so?